# HTMLagilitypack is not removing all html tags How can I solve this efficiently?

Tags: c#, string, html-agility-pack

I am using following method to strip all html from the string:

```
public static string StripHtmlTags(string html)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) return "";
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            return doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
        }
```

But it seems ignoring this following tag: `[&#8230;]`

So the string returns basicly:

```
> A hungry thief who stole a rack of pork ribs from a grocery store has
> been sentenced to spend 50 years in prison. Willie Smith Ward felt the
> full force of the law after being convicted of the crime in Waco,
> Texas, on Wednesday. The 43-year-old may feel slightly aggrieved over
> the severity of the [&#8230;]
```

How can I make sure that these kind of tags gets stripped?

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `&#8230;` is not an HTML tag. A tag has angle brackets. This is an encoded entity.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`

```
public static string StripHtmlTags(string html)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) return "";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);
}
```

HtmlDecode will convert `[&#8230;]` to `[…]`

Comment: I suggest using WebUtility.HtmlDecode instead of HttpUtility.HtmlDecode if you are using .NET 4+. It doesn't require System.Web reference.

Comment: @Damit would this be a better approach if not why ?   doc.LoadHtml(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html));

Comment: You can also combine that with a Trim() to remove aditional unwanted whitespaces and carriage returns that get in your way.

Comment: You can also use HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(sText.InnerText) from HTMLAgilityPack - no need to reference other libraries in this case.