# DiffPlex does not ignore html tags while comparing two html codes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

Well I am using DIFFPlex for comparing two html code fetching from db but i want to ignore html tags and their styling (only content), is there any way to achieve this.
I am waiting for your answer guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the HtmlAgilityPack to strip all the html tags.

See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875574/12919

Comment: but still want html tags when displaying compared code as page. want to compare text only not html tags

Comment: You need three versions of each side of your diff (docA / docB).  The original html from the database, the content (stripped of html) and the html with extra formatting used to display the differences.  You will diff docA content and docB content after using HtmlAgilityPack to strip the html.  Then build a new set of html with extra formatting to display the differences.